# C++ Outlook Object Model get shared calendar folder

Tags: c++, visual-c++, outlook, mapi, outlook-object-model

I want to user GetCalendarExporter() on contact folder of shared calendar.

I have written code which I feel will give only default calendar folder(i.e. Owner's calendar folder). I want Shared(Delegated) Calendar folder object/pointer. Any idea how to do that?

As of now my code is like:

```
CComPtr<Olk::_NameSpace> spNameSpace = spApplication->GetNamespace(L"MAPI");

Olk::MAPIFolderPtr spCalFolder = spNameSpace->GetDefaultFolder(Olk::olFolderCalendar);

spCalFolder->GetCalendarExporter();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method which returns a `Folder` object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders (for example, their shared Calendar folder).

```
Sub ResolveName() 
 Dim myNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace 
 Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set myNamespace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
 Set myRecipient = myNamespace.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev") 
 myRecipient.Resolve 
 If myRecipient.Resolved Then 
   Call ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 End If 
End Sub 
 
Sub ShowCalendar(myNamespace, myRecipient) 
 Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder 
 Set CalendarFolder = myNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar) 
 CalendarFolder.Display 
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Eugene Astafiev, Thanks for your answer. Just one question, GetSharedDefaultFolder() requires recipient to be resolved and passed as input parameter. What if I don't have recipient? What I want to do is. Want to apply CalendarFolder->GetCalendarExporter(); Where CalendarFolder is Shared folder.

Comment: You must know the person who has shared the calendar to get the calendar folder. Use the [CreateRecipient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.createrecipient) method to create a recipient object.

Comment: Thanks Eugene Astafiev